# Invalid constant value

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform, mobile-development

I created a method below to loop through my list because I don't want to write again and again of these few lines but the parameter I pass to the Text widget and also value argument are error and it said Invalid constant value. How can I achieve this? I'm new to flutter. Please help me.

```
  PopupMenuItem _createMenuItems(final String a) {
    return const PopupMenuItem(
      value: a,
      child: Text(a),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have your tried simply returning PopupMenuItem without `const` modifier like below?

```
PopupMenuItem _createMenuItems(final String a) {
   return PopupMenuItem(
     value: a,
     child: Text(a),
   );
}
```

Comment: This answer misses remark about what's lost when removing "const". Why did the code say "const" in the first place?